# Let $f,g\in{\rm Aut}(G)$. Show $f\circ g$ and $f^{-1}$ are also automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group and let ${\rm Aut}(G)$ be the set of all automorphisms of $G$.

> 1. Let $f,g\in{\rm Aut}(G)$. Show that $f\circ g$ is also an automorphism of $G$.
> 2. Let $f\in{\rm Aut}(G)$. Show that $f^{−1}$ is also an automorphism of $G$.

For #1 we N.T.S that $f \circ g$ is a bijection and a homomorphism.

First we will show onto.  Let $f \circ g: A \to C$ with $g(A)=B$ and $f(B)=C$.  $f\circ g(A)=f(g(A))=f(B)=C$ so $f\circ g$ is onto.

Now we will show 1-1.  Let $a,b$ exist in $f \circ g$.  $f \circ  g(a)=f \circ g(b)$ which means $f(g(a))=f(g(b))$ which means $g(a)=g(b)$ which shows $a=b$.  So this is 1-1.

Now we will need to show $f \circ g$ is a homorphism.  $f \circ g(ab)=f(g(ab))=f(g(a)g(b))=f(g(a))f(g(b))=f \circ g(a)f \circ g(b)$ for all $a,b$ in $G$.  So $f \circ g$ forms a homomorphism.

For #2 can we use the facts that we proved in #1 that since $f$ is a homomorphism and $f$ is a bijection then $f^{-1}$ must be as well?  Is there anything else I have to prove besides homomorphisms and bijections for these two?

Comment: What do you mean by "Let $a,b$ exist in $f\circ g$"?

Comment: You should compare your efforts also with the standard proof, say, at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138613/proving-a-set-of-automorphisms-of-a-group-is-a-group-under-composition): Suppose that $f:G\rightarrow G$ is a group isomorphism. We need to show that $f^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism. Let $a,b\in G$. By definition there exist a unique $x,y\in G$ such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$. Hence $$f^{-1}(ab)=f^{-1}(f(x)f(y))=f^{-1}(f(xy))=xy.$$
Similarly $$f^{-1}(a)f^{-1}(b)=f^{-1}(f(x))f^{-1}(f(y))=xy.$$
Hence $f^{-1}(ab)=f^{-1}(a)f^{-1}(b).$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $f^{-1}$ is an automorphism, note that, indeed, since $f$ is a bijection, its inverse is one too. (Why?)

What's left is showing that $f^{-1}:B\to A$ is an homomorphism. Let $b, b'\in B$. Then

$$\begin{align}
f(f^{-1}(b)f^{-1}(b'))&=f(f^{-1}(b))f(f^{-1}(b'))\\
&=bb'.
\end{align}$$

Now apply $f^{-1}$.

Comment: when you say now apply $f^{-1}$ at the end of the proof does this mean you have to show $f^{-1}(f(b)f(b'))$ or is the proof done?  What you mean by that?

Comment: @user710744: We have $$\begin{align} f^{-1}(b)f^{-1}(b')&=\color{red}{f^{-1}}(f(f^{-1}(b)f^{-1}(b'))) \\ &=\color{red}{f^{-1}}(bb').\end{align}$$

Comment: So this is showing it's a homomorphism.  I don't get why you are mixing f's and $f^{-1}$ in each example you wrote.  How does the first example apply to what we are doing?

Comment: Also I just want to make sure is the work for the first problem correct?

Comment: Yes, it's showing it's a homomorphism. Again: $$\begin{align} f^{-1}(b)f^{-1}(b')&=\color{red}{f^{-1}}(\color{blue}{f(f^{-1}(b)f^{-1}(b'))}) \\ &=\color{red}{f^{-1}}(\color{blue}{bb'}).\end{align}$$ This is because $f^{-1}\circ f$ is the identity map, @user710744.

Comment: Okay that makes sense I see what your saying thank you for your help, so the first part what I wrote in the beginning is that correct too?  It's pretty basic stuff but just want to make sure it's right....

Comment: My only criticism of the first part is [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415572/let-f-g-in-rm-autg-show-f-circ-g-and-f-1-are-also-automorphisms/3415614#comment7024675_3415572). The rest is okay, @user710744.